# How to Use Cypress with AngularJS application

Tags: cypress, angular

Our legacy Application is developed with AngularJS(app folder in the picture) but now started with nx (Angular) for the new feature development (which is in `web-apps` within the app).

My question is NX by default support cypress, where as AngularJS does not support cypress. I want to add cypress at root level directly (which is on AngularJS) level and should also support XN developed features.
i want to write e2e test cases that can run on jenkins pipeline once before the build.

Comment: Component tests or end-to-end? In the latter case it shouldn't matter to your tests which (if any) front-end framework is in use; Cypress just drives the browser.

Comment: @MaryumKhan What have you tried so far? Have you seen any error or problem?

Comment: i want to write e2e test cases that can run on jenkins pipeline once before the build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Use Cypress with AngularJS application and Angular as well](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/51650/how-to-use-cypress-with-angularjs-application-and-angular-as-well)

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is browser automation and is not typically specific to a development framework.  It may or may not be installed in the same repo as the application code.

To use it you do need to install it, e.g. `npm install cypress -D` and have it in your package.json for the project you want. Or a higher level directory in the git repo. Or a separate repo.  I recommend keeping it in the same repo as it encourages more use by app devs. It then becomes a dependency of the project in order to run cypress but not of the Angular application itself.

Comment: i want to write e2e test cases that can run on jenkins pipeline once before the build.
does it make any difference if i have angular and angularJS both in one repository,

Comment: Is your question about building different Angular applications in Jenkins using one repo?  If so it is not about cypress and is about application configuration and maybe belongs on the main site.